# Axes pointing in both directions and positioning axes labels (Tikz). AD-AS Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to reproduce a graph like this one but I don't know how to make the axis as in the picture. Does anyone know how to?
An similar example that doesn't have axis pointing both ways is:

```
% Author: Rasmus Pank Roulund
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{comment}
:Title: Intersection of
:Tags: Coordinate systems


This example shows how the ``intersection of`` mechanism of Tikz work. Notice how a horizontal 
line is made from point B to allow the calculation to be done.

Caption: In a fixed exchange regime it might not be possible to reach internal balance 
(full employment and price stability) and external balance (some given level of net export) 
using only fiscal policy. At point B only point C and D can be reached via fiscal policy. 
Only by devaluing the country is able to reach the optimum level at point A.

:Author: Rasmus Pank Roulund

\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=5,
    axis/.style={very thick, ->, >=stealth'},
    important line/.style={thick},
    dashed line/.style={dashed, thin},
    pile/.style={thick, ->, >=stealth', shorten <=2pt, shorten
    >=2pt},
    every node/.style={color=black}
    ]
    % axis
    \draw[axis] (-0.1,0)  -- (1.1,0) node(xline)[right]
        {$G\uparrow/T\downarrow$};
    \draw[axis] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1.1) node(yline)[above] {$E$};
    % Lines
    \draw[important line] (.15,.15) coordinate (A) -- (.85,.85)
        coordinate (B) node[right, text width=5em] {$Y^O$};
    \draw[important line] (.15,.85) coordinate (C) -- (.85,.15)
        coordinate (D) node[right, text width=5em] {$\mathit{NX}=x$};
    % Intersection of lines
    \fill[red] (intersection cs:
       first line={(A) -- (B)},
       second line={(C) -- (D)}) coordinate (E) circle (.4pt)
       node[above,] {$A$};
    % The E point is placed more or less randomly
    \fill[red]  (E) +(-.075cm,-.2cm) coordinate (out) circle (.4pt)
        node[below left] {$B$};
    % Line connecting out and ext balances
    \draw [pile] (out) -- (intersection of A--B and out--[shift={(0:1pt)}]out)
        coordinate (extbal);
    \fill[red] (extbal) circle (.4pt) node[above] {$C$};
    % line connecting  out and int balances
    \draw [pile] (out) -- (intersection of C--D and out--[shift={(0:1pt)}]out)
        coordinate (intbal);
    \fill[red] (intbal) circle (.4pt) node[above] {$D$};
    % line between out og all balanced out :)
    \draw[pile] (out) -- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: My current code is:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=5,
    axis/.style={very thick, <->, >=stealth'},
    important line/.style={thick},
    every node/.style={color=black}
    ]
    % axis
    \draw[axis] (0.1,0)  -- (1.1,0) node(xline)[right] {$Y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0.1) -- (0,1.1) node(yline)[above] {$\pi_s$};
    % Lines
    \draw[important line] (.15,.15) coordinate (A) -- (.85,.85)
        coordinate (B) node[right, text width=5em] {$AS$};
    \draw[important line] (.15,.85) coordinate (C) -- (.85,.15)
        coordinate (D) node[right, text width=5em] {$AD$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Fabio
[image]

Solution:
For those who are interested in a AD-AS diagram, this is what I managed to achieve so far. I think it's pretty decent:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=5,
    axis/.style={very thick, <->, >=stealth'},
    important line/.style={thick},
    every node/.style={color=black}
    ]
    % axis
    \draw[axis] (0.1,0)  -- (1.1,0) node(xline)[midway,below] {$\hat{Y}$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0.1) -- (0,1.1) node(yline)[midway,left] {$  \hat{\pi}_s$};
    % Lines
    \draw[important line] (.15,.15) coordinate (A) -- (.85,.85)
        coordinate (B) node[right, text width=5em] {$AS$};
    \draw[important line] (.15,.85) coordinate (C) -- (.85,.15)
        coordinate (D) node[right, text width=5em] {$AD$};
    %shifted IS-LM diagram
    \draw[xshift=.2cm, red!52] (.15,.10) coordinate (A) -- (.85,.80)
    coordinate (B) node[right, text width=5em] {$AS'$};

    %arrows between intersections
    \draw[->, thick, black, >=stealth']
    (0.61,.59) -- (.72,.48)
    node[sloped, above, midway] {$\hat{\tau}^w_S$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I edited the topic narrowing it down to the axes issue, which is the main problem at the moment.

Comment: isn't `<->` instead of `->` what you are looking for?

Comment: @daleif yeah! as easy as that. I'm trying to learn more from the manual, but this specific kind of graph is not much discussed and I can't find how to change the position of the axes' labels, to center them. I tried different specifications of [right] and [above], but whatever I specify, they don't go where I want.

Comment: @FabioI. `[midway,left]` or `[pos=0.5,left]`, there are lots of examples in the start og the manual

Comment: Instead of marking the question as “Solved”, which is not the site's policy, you should provide an answer.

Comment: @egreg sorry, I'm still familiarising with the site. The answer is already provided though

Comment: @FabioI. It should be a proper answer in the space below

Answer (score 1):

To get arrow heads at both ends use `<->` instead of `->`.

To write a label above the middle of an arrow use

```
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node[midway,above]{A};
```

`midway` is an alias for `pos=0.5`.